# XPath 2.0 - 1.0 equivalent?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I have trouble in producing valid XPath 1.0 equivalent of a working 2.0 example which would produce the same results (and, in fact, not fail). The reason I have to use the previous version is that PHP does not support XPath 2.0.

My xml looks like:

```
<root>
    <container id="1">
        <elements>
            <element value="0"/>
        </elements>
    </container>
    <container id="2">
        <elements>
            <element value="1"/>
        </elements>
    </container>
    <container id="3">
        <elements>
            <element value="1"/>
        </elements>
    </container>
</root>
```

I would like to to get the `value` attribute of the `element` node, of which the grandparent `container` node has the attribute `id` equal to 1 or 3. Also I would like to get the aforementioned id attribute concatenated to the corresponding `element` `value` attribute. If the previous two statements are not exactly readable (my English is kind of rusty these days), that's what I would like to achieve:

```
1:0
3:1
```

The format is:

```
[container id]:[element value]
```

A working XPath 2.0 path which I wrote gives the expected result:

```
//container[@id=1 or @id=3]//element/concat(../../@id, ":", @value)
```

However, running this on using a [XPath 1.0 tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) results in the following error:

```
ERROR - Failed to evaluate XPath expression: Unknown nodetype: concat
```

Which puzzles me, since concat is present in the [XPath 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-concat).

I tried using different approaches, like using a path like this:

```
//container[@id=1 or @id=3]/@id | //container[@id=1 or @id=3]//element/@value
```

Which gives a result set like this:

```
1
0
3
1
```

Which I can parse problematically to achieve the expected format but I am not sure if the union will pair the corresponding `id` and `value` correctly. Can anyone point me into a proper direction?

Comment: `concat` returns a string in XPath 1.0. You can process one node with this: `concat(//container[@id = 1]/@id,':',//element[../../@id = 1]/@value)`

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it, however it will be really inefficient to use this method when there will be a variable list of `id`s

Comment: You can perhaps try using using the XPath inside a XSLT stylesheet, and use XSLTProcessor to obtain the data. I believe it's avaliable for previous versions of PHP

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this in plain XPath 1.0. There is no way to do any kind of explicit loops, let it be the simplified FLWOR expressions of XPath 2.0 or applying functions as axis steps.

Fetch the containers in XPath, and do further processing outside XPath, or embed an XPath 2.0 (or XQuery, which is a superset) processor.

Answer (score 3):

The result of your XPath 2.0 expression is a sequence of strings. That's a data type that doesn't even exist in XPath 1.0. So you'll basically have to do more of the work in the host language.